# Keep Centered Edge Text Rotate imagettftext()

Tags: php, gd

I Try to rotate Text using GD Library, while keeping centered edge of the rotation (like photoshop or CSS3 Transform),

But, the result isn't same like Photoshop or CSS3. Edge point of the text is "Top Left", not centered.

I try this trick for rotate Images: [StackOverflow: Php Gd rotate image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/780993/php-gd-rotate-image#answer-8379681)

That trick just work for Image.
I create blank Image, (create imgae, and add the text), then I apllied that trick to created image.
But still not work.

Any suggestions?